# Find multiple lines between two lines (regular expression)

Tags: regex

trying to capture some specific lines between two set lines

**MSG   753202 SHOWING SENTENCE** (BETWEEN THIS)
753202    195.1   554.2  1709.0 ...
753203    194.8   554.4  1706.0 ...
753257    196.9   566.0  1638.0 ...
753262    195.8   564.4  1631.0 ...
753263    195.8   564.1  1631.0 ...
EFIX R   753140 753263  124   195.5   555.5    1710 (THIS)
753285     91.4   560.1  1614.0 ...
753286     89.0   559.7  1612.0 ...
753287     85.9   559.2  1610.0 ...
EFIX R   753288 753494  207    67.7   569.0    1545 (THIS)
753291     73.2   559.3  1609.0 ...

**MSG   753202 SHOWING GONE** (AND THIS)

and then return the lines in-between.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: There are several lines of course

Comment: Please format your question properly and mention your attempt and what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, for a first start. I mean then you could adapt it to your need:

```
sed -n '/MSG 753202 SHOWING SENTENCE/,/MSG 753202 SHOWING GONE/ { p;}' file.txt
```

See the [Ranges by patterns in Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29).

The test is below:

```
 sed -n '/MSG 753202 SHOWING SENTENCE/,/MSG 753202 SHOWING GONE/ { p;}' file.txt
MSG 753202 SHOWING SENTENCE (BETWEEN THIS) 753202 195.1 554.2 1709.0 ... 753203 194.8 554.4 1706.0 ... 753257 196.9 566.0 1638.0 ... 753262 195.8 564.4 1631.0 ... 753263 195.8 564.1 1631.0 ... EFIX R 753140 753263 124 195.5 555.5 1710 (THIS) 753285 91.4 560.1 1614.0 ... 753286 89.0 559.7 1612.0 ... 753287 85.9 559.2 1610.0 ... EFIX R 753288 753494 207 67.7 569.0 1545 (THIS) 753291 73.2 559.3 1609.0 ...

MSG 753202 SHOWING GONE (AND THIS)
```